# how is ORM an example of message coupling?

Tags: coupling

In [this slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/dogmatic69/coupling-and-cohesion) on slide 26 it mentions ORM as an example of message coupling. How is that so?

With an ORM, certain code will call the ORM via an API, but that sounds like "control coupling". Also the ORM's api will take parameters to specify what you want, but that sounds like data coupling.

How is ORM an example of message coupling? maybe other examples of message coupling will help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fundamental principles of object orientation is "message passing."  Large object-oriented systems work by passing messages between objects.  Those messages can contain commands or data.  When I set a property on an object, I'm sending a data message.  When I call a method on an object, I'm sending a command message; I am dictating what action to take by choosing the method to call.  When I pass parameters to that method, I am sending a data message with the command message.

Message coupling in ORM's refers to both command messaging and data messaging.  I think it's fair to say that most messages in an ORM take the form of Create, Read, Update or Delete command messages.  There are methods corresponding to each of these command messages, and parameters that accept the data messages to be acted upon.

Coupling in an ORM refers to the fact that, when you make a call to an ORM, you must have some awareness of the data that you want.  Is it customers or products?  Later on in the slide, the author states that the only way to have no coupling at all is to have an empty reformatted hard drive (a blank slate, without any shape to the data, just random bits).

Data without shape is not meaningful or useful, so the first thing we do is we create shapes: customer records, product records, etc.  Once you do that, you've created coupling, because you have to know what a customer record or product record looks like in order to retrieve it and do anything useful with it.

Comment: That makes sense -- but then I have a follow up question: what is the difference between "control coupling" and "data coupling" vs "message coupling"? At some point, I feel like we define message coupling to the point that it has no useful meaning left.

Comment: For our purposes here, control coupling and command coupling are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, would you mind confirming that the following is correct? _What the ORM does depends on the message it gets. If you send it some sort of Create command message, it'll create something. If you send it some sort of Delete command message, it'll delete something. So in that sense, what the ORM does is coupled to the message it receives. When put that way, if the ORM's behavior wasn't coupled to the messages it receives, it would be behaving like a lunatic!_